# How to alternatively change BackColor of RTB text

Tags: c#, winforms

I've got a requirement to change text backcolor in RTB. RTB is getting created in a loop for number of messages from DB.
I implemented a logic to achieve it but feel logic as simple.
So could you be able to give idea to implement same or mine is fine?

**Code:**

```
foreach (DataSet.NoteRow note in _ds.Note)
        {
            CreateNotes(note);
        }
private void CreateNotes(string note)
{
//txt : Rich Text Box dynamically created for each note
//test : Selected text in 'note'
int index = txt.Text.ToUpper().IndexOf(test.ToUpper());
txt.Select(index, test.Length);
txt.SelectionFont = new Font(txt.Font.Name, txt.Font.Size, txt.Font.Style^ FontStyle.Bold);
//x global variable initialised as 1
if(x % 2 == 1)
txt.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
x++;  }
```

**Scenario :**
If Notes has 5 messages, then alternative message should have gray backcolor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
private void CreateNotes(string note)
{
//txt : Rich Text Box dynamically created for each note
//test : Selected text in 'note'
int index = txt.Text.ToUpper().IndexOf(test.ToUpper());
txt.Select(index, test.Length);
txt.SelectionFont = new Font(txt.Font.Name, txt.Font.Size, txt.Font.Style^ FontStyle.Bold);
 Random rnd = new Random();

//x global variable initialised as 1
if(x % 2 == 1)
txt.SelectionBackColor = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255));
x++;  }
```

Comment: i would be happy if logic change is on this line `if(x % 2 ==1)`
something like counting no of messages and can we use it anyway??

Comment: m not getting u logic what u want exactly

Comment: lets assume i have 5 messages. so when first message gets in, `x` will be 1 and in condition `if(x % 2 ==1)` satisfies and applies color.   
For 2nd message, `x` will be 2 and condition fails so no BackColor..Flow will continue..this logic is working....i'm asking is there any other efficient way to achieve this.